# sed :unknown option to `s' in my sed script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

So i have a script named SED.sed. The script was made to work on a data set of car data, to clarify i want to first explain the desired function for my script.
I want to do 3 things

1. replace years with decades. The set only contains cars from 1970-89 so we replace the year with the appropriate decade. ex (1972 and 1974 will be replaced with 70s)
2. the cars make and model are given under a pair of double quotes. I replaced them with single quotes and seperate the make from model. So "Honda civic lx" "audi 500s (diesel)" turns into 'honda' 'civic lx' and 'audi' '500s (diesel)'
3. some data lines contained " ? " if there was data missing. I wanted to delete these lines from the data set.

that being said my script looks like the following

```
s/"([^" ]+) +([^"]+)"$/'"'\1' '\2'/"
s/7[0-9]( )/70s/g
s/8[0-9]( )/80s/g
/?/d
```

I then pass this script into the sed command like so
`sed -E -i -f SED.sed auto-mpg.data`

which gives me the following error
`` sed: file SED.sed line 1: unknown option to `s' ``

Comment: You've got an extra character (the last double quote) after the trailing slash that is terminating the replacement expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I deleted the `"` at the end of line 1, which produced an error message on line 4, so I could pinpoint the problem. The problem was occurring in the 4th line with the `?` symbol. I added a backslash before it and not the script runs.

Comment: That's possible, but not the cause of the error message referring to line 1

Comment: @roaima oops! i edited the answer to fully include what i did. Sorry, still new to this.